# Can I get UI thread context while using 'async/await'

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, mvvm, async-await

I want to know if its possible to get UI Thread context when using Asyn/await method. If yes, how?

Code written using WPF/MVVM pattern:

```
long asyncTimeChecker = 0;
int prevSec2 = 0;

/// <summary>
/// Button Click Command
/// </summary>
private void ExeTimerActivate(object o)
{
   if (!IsTimerStart)
   {
      ActivateAsyncTicToc();
      TimerState = "Stop";
   }
   else if (IsTimerStart)
   {
      ActivateAsyncTicToc();
      TimerState = "Start";
   }

   IsTimerStart = !IsTimerStart;
}        

/// <summary>
/// Call Method By Async/Await
/// </summary>
private async void ActivateAsyncTicToc()
{
  IsTimerStartAsync = !IsTimerStartAsync;

  var task1 = Task.Run(() => AsyncTicToc());
  await task1;
}



/// <summary>
/// I tried to UI access by other thread what use Async/Await
/// </summary>
private void AsyncTicToc()
{
  while (IsTimerStartAsync)
  {
      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
      AsyncTimeText = $"{asyncTimeChecker / 1000}.{asyncTimeChecker % 1000}";
      asyncTimeChecker += 10;

      /// ========================================
      /// This Position Get CrossThread Problem
      /// ========================================
      if (prevSec2 < asyncTimeChecker / 1000)
      {
           prevSec2++;
           if (TimerColor2.Color == Colors.Blue)
               TimerColor2.Color = Colors.Red;
           else
               TimerColor2.Color = Colors.Blue;
       }
   }
```

}

I know we can get the UI thread using Dispatcher, but want to know if its possible using async/await.

Comment: @Bharathi Thanks for correct my context more clearlly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are wrapping your `async` call in a task. This defeats the whole statemachine, and ends up using a threadpool thread needlessly.

The call and any continuations ends up in another thread and therefore can't access the UI without marshalling.

At minimum you should be doing this if you absolutely need to use an `async` `void` - it's just awaiting the task, and not wrapping it.

```
private async void ActivateAsyncTicToc()
{
   try
   {
      IsTimerStartAsync = !IsTimerStartAsync;    
      await AsyncTicToc();
   }
   catch (Exception e)
   {
      // make sure you observe exceptions in async void
   }
}
```

Even better, let the `async` propagate using `async Task`:

```
private async Task ActivateAsyncTicToc()
{
   IsTimerStartAsync = !IsTimerStartAsync;    
   await AsyncTicToc();
}
```

Which looks suspect anyway, you should probably be doing this (eliding `async` and `await`) and just passing the task through to someone else who will await. This is a small performance gain:

```
private Task ActivateAsyncTicToc()
{
   IsTimerStartAsync = !IsTimerStartAsync;    
   return AsyncTicToc();
}
```

In fact this is a mine-field and I'd be here all day.

You need to start reading about `async` and `await`:

- [Stephen Cleary Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html)
- [Stephen Cleary Eliding Async and Await](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2016/12/eliding-async-await.html)
- [Stephen Cleary Don't Block on Async Code](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html)
- [Asynchronous programming with async and await (C#)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/concepts/async/)
- [Using Async And Await To Update The Ui Thread](https://stephenhaunts.com/2014/10/14/using-async-and-await-to-update-the-ui-thread/)

Comment: Didn't quite get difference between first and second code snippets. Do you want to say that first code snippet is bad?

Comment: @AccessDenied yeah just saying that there is no point awaiting in this situation, just pass the task along saving some overhead (Eliding Async and Await)

Comment: @TheGeneral Thanks a lot for a commit! i checked your answer late. and i read the acticles you linked up, and i found solution the last link! and also I really thanks that the links really helped me, and i reallize that i think wrong. due to your help my curious solved! Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you could use `await Task.Delay(10)` instead of `Thread.Sleep(10)` and change your `AsyncTicToc` method to `async Task` without starting a thread. This will make changing the control in the UI thread (the context from which you awaited).

Second, to update the UI from other threads, if you don't want to use the dispatcher directly, you can use the abstraction over it: the [SynchronizationContext](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.synchronizationcontext?view=netframework-4.7.2) class. See more info [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/31971/Understanding-SynchronizationContext-Part-I).

Example: `SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(action, actionParameter);`

Third, It's more appropriate to use a view model and binding. If you use WPF that it synchronizes the threads for property changes for you.

Comment: Thanks a lot! i solved problem with **SynchronizationContext.Current.Post(action, actionParameter);** Thanks!

Comment: @M.JiHong: Please mark this as the answer, then; there should be a big check mark next to the number of this question. Also consider upvoting the answer by clicking the up arrow. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

While it is possible to "reach out" from another thread to the UI thread using `Dispatcher` or `SynchronizationContext`, I strongly recommend not doing this. This is because it makes your logic less testable and more tied to its environment. In the case of `Dispatcher`, it is strongly tied to running in a WPF environment; `SynchronizationContext` is better, but it is still tied to running in some kind of environment.

With this kind of an approach, you have a dependency from your logic to a UI thread like this:

UI code => background thread logic => UI thread

Instead, use `IProgress<T>` and `Progress<T>` from your background thread logic to communicate progress reports back to its caller, which decides how to display those progress reports. Then your dependency looks like this:

UI code => background thread logic

and your background thread logic doesn't rely on a UI thread being present. This makes it more resuable and more testable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for answer!! I read  your answer, and i understand **IProgress** you said. And i try IProgress in my code.
1. button click -> Call Command
2. TestClass iherit IProcess<Action>
3. while(EndButtonActivate) { UI Update code }
like this. But that thread can't update UI with run time error.
what's problem with me? Thanks!

Comment: [your blog](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/09/taskrun-vs-backgroundworker-round-5.html) i got it! i learned new knowlege today, thanks to you!